# Re-using an ejected flash drive

Tags: macos, automount, flash-memory

I tried to properly eject a flash drive by moving it into Trash. It went up in that little puff of smoke. Now when I try to reuse the drive by plugging it back into the computer, it does not show up in my Finder. What gives? (I am running Yosemite.)

Comment: Did you tried to reboot ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might have dragged it out of the Sidebar on your Finder Window. Try this: plug the drive back in, and then hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   to go to your Computer view. You should see all your connected drives there; just drag the drive you want back to the Sidebar.

Comment: Cmd+C is copy? Just keep on doing Cmd+Up Arrow until you reach the top level and you'll see all the drives there.

Comment: It's cmd/shift/c - I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The little puff of smoke was the giveaway…

Next time, notice that in the sidebar, removable drives have a little up arrow.
Click that to eject.

[image]

Alternatively, select the drive itself & use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd> 
or right click in the drive's contents & select "Eject my SD Card"